# Windows 10 UWP Authenticate with web server

Tags: php, authentication, uwp

I made an API for PHP which provides data to the Windows 10 UWP app to load data from MySQL. I would like to make sure that only the app has access to that data and people can't just check it out from a browser. Do you guys have any idea how to do it? Can I send a unique id from my app and check if it is real on the back end of the PHP server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to authenticate your users. You could pass the Appid in the header.

```
string appId = CurrentApp.AppId.ToString();
```

and only allow gets and posts with information included to use your api. It might be better to use an authentication service like an oath provider. This would be a much more secure way to go. Someone could easily  spoof your app if you are not using https to communicate with your backend.